# WPF Extended Toolkit CheckComboBox doesn't display items

Tags: c#, wpf, toolkit

In my WPF application, I'm trying to use a CheckComboBox from the Extended Toolkit. The CheckComboBox has items, I can select them, and the selected items are correcticaly stored in a List. But the items in the CheckComboBox are blank, something like that :

[x]

[x]

[x]

[x]

Here is my code :

```
<extToolkit:CheckComboBox Name="cbTypes" 
ItemsSource="{Binding AllTypes}" 
SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding ChosenTypes}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

AllTypes is an array of objects, the objects have a Name (string) property and 2 other string property

What's weird is that it work withs a basic ComBox, I can see my items

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Convert AllTypes  to List first, then tell me result.

Comment: It is already a List, sorry

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't find any solution... I made a copy of my list of objects into a list of strings with only the names, then I has able to see the items in the checkcombobox.

It is not the right solution I guess but it solved by problem